# ReactComponent vs ReactComponentElement in scalajs-react

Tags: reactjs, scalajs-react

I am  trying to write some extra [scalajs-react documentation](https://github.com/jhegedus42/scalajs-react-playaround/wiki/React#how-do-scalajs-react-types-map-to-js-react-types-) but I am confused.

It says [here](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/TYPES.md#plain-dom-elements) :

> A `ReactElement` is a `ReactDOMElement` or a React component.

But it says [here](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/fcb1b6ab493b0c77d589#formal-type-definitions):

> `type ReactElement = ReactComponentElement | ReactDOMElement;`

Which one is true ?

How can one explain this contradiction ?

How can `ReactComponent` and `ReactComponentElement` be the same ?

I am confused. Can someone please unconfuse me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm over simplifying, but the source code indicates that a ReactElement is a javascript object with the properties of a ReactNode and `key` and `ref` properties. I wouldn't put as much stock in the vDom / scaladoc comments. They exist to provide a hint to the user, not the compiler. It's trying to say "ReactElement is the common base trait to ReactComponentElement and ReactDomElement", which you can see is indeed true.

```
   /** ReactElement = ReactComponentElement | ReactDOMElement  */
@js.native
trait ReactElement extends Object with ReactNode {
  def key: UndefOr[String] = js.native
  def ref: UndefOr[String] = js.native
}

/** A React virtual DOM element, such as 'div', 'table', etc. */
@js.native
trait ReactDOMElement extends ReactElement {
  def `type`: String = js.native
  def props : Object = js.native
}

/** An instance of a React component. Prefer using the subtype ReactComponentU instead. */
@js.native
trait ReactComponentElement[Props]
  extends ReactElement
     with HasProps[Props]
```

The key thing here is that React is a a fairly dynamic javascript framework, so in order to add type safety around it scala.js there end up being a number of "similar but not identical" subtypes create to handle the various underlying states. For instance, `ReactComponentU` and friends and `ReactComponent`/`ReactComponentElement`.

I think in order to document it (more?) successfully than it already has been, you probably will have to document React itself, and then paper over it with the type system -- trying to explain things strictly in terms of the scala.js interface is likely to be quite confusing.